# Detect face in video file

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

My code is to detect face in a video, but the video is not being loaded even I have given the right path. Also, I installed ffmpeg but there are no .dll files in it.

Can anyone help?

```
import cv2

import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:\\OPENCV\\opencv\\sources\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

ret,cam=cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\New folder (5)\\New folder (3)\\Ae Dil Hai Mushkil.mp4')

img=cam.read()

while(cam.isOpened()):

ret,img=cam.read();

if not ret: break

gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5);

    `enter code here`for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.imshow("Face",img);
    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q')):
        break;

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\New folder (5)\New folder (3)\facedet.py", line 5, in <module>
    ret,cam=cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\New folder (5)\\New folder (3)\\Ae Dil Hai Mushkil.mp4')
TypeError: 'cv2.VideoCapture' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please fix indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing:

```
ret,cam=cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\New folder (5)\\New folder (3)\\Ae Dil Hai Mushkil.mp4')

img=cam.read()
```

To:

```
cam=cv2.VideoCapture('D:\\New folder (5)\\New folder (3)\\Ae Dil Hai Mushkil.mp4')

ret,img=cam.read()
```

Comment: There is neither any error nor any output.Its blank.I cant understand whats happening